# Resources (.resx) works in VS2013, but not in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, localization, resx

The problem is that resources (.resx) globalization works in VS2013, but doesn't in VS2010.

I have a .NET4 solution created with VS2013 with a class library and a test project.
I manage my resources with a folder/namespace "Resources" under which I add my .resx files.
I created two methods in Class1.cs to test the resources.

[sample http://www.insidelsci.ca/Images/slnSample.png](http://www.insidelsci.ca/Images/slnSample.png)

I then call the two static methods in my test project.

When I run it in VS2013, it works fine. 
When I run it in VS2010, it always returns the default resource (never the .fr.resx).

It works the other way around (for a solution created in VS2010 opened with VS2013).

Any idea why it always returns the default value?
Thank you!

[slnResources.zip](http://www.insidelsci.ca/slnResources.zip)

Comment: what happens if you load ("fr") instead of ("fr-CA")

Comment: Same. 
Resource1.fr will apply to all fr culture (fr-CA, fr-FR, etc.)